# IntelliJ IDEA : Spring Boot vs JAR Application configurations

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Spring Boot project. I created the following two configurations:

1. Spring Boot Configuration
   [image]
2. JAR Application Configuration
   [image]

Can someone tell me what is the difference? They both run as expected.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Running via Spring Boot configuration will allow hot swapping of the changes during debugging which is very useful during development as you don't have to rebuild all the files and package the jar on every change.

Jar Application is handy when you want to verify that your production jar works as expected.